# Unable to catch DriveNotFoundException from Get-PSDrive

Tags: powershell

I'm unable to catch the `DriveNotFoundException` being generated by `Get-PSDrive` in the following example:

```
try {
    # Assumes no Q:\ drive connected.
    $foo = Get-PSDrive -name 'Q' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException] {
    Write-Output "Drive not found."
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Something else went wrong."
}
```

This should print the following:

```
PS C:\temp> .\foo.ps1
Drive not found.
PS C:\temp>
```

Instead, I get:

```
PS C:\temp> .\foo.ps1
Something else went wrong.
PS C:\temp>
```

I'm using Powershell 2.0, if that's relevant.

Comment: This works for me on 4.0. Wonder if the exception type is different on 2.0

Comment: Yep, works fine in 5.0.

Comment: Thanks.  You've both validated that I'm not crazy.  I couldn't see any reason why this wasn't working.  Unfortunately, some of the servers that are going to run this particular script have 2.0 installed, so I'm having to write it for the least common denominator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because the `-ErrorAction Stop` is changing the Exception type that the try/catch block is seeing.

You can prove it by catching the `ActionPreferenceStopException` type. So let's run some troubleshooting code to see what is going on:

```
try {
    # Assumes no Q:\ drive connected.
    $foo = Get-PSDrive -name 'Q' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException] {
    Write-Output "Drive not found."
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException] {
    Write-Output "Stop Exception."
    write-host "Caught an exception:" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
catch
{
    write-host "Caught an exception:" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

This returns the following output:

```
Stop Exception.
Caught an exception:
Exception Type: System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException
Exception Message: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Q' does not exist.
```

So you see that the try/catch caught the `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]` exception, **Even Though** the Exception type *is* `[System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException]` *inside* the catch block.

So, we can handle it with a slightly modified version of @haliphax's solution, which is to check the error type inside the `ActionPreferenceStopException` catch block:

```
try {
    # Assumes no Q:\ drive connected.
    $foo = Get-PSDrive -name 'Q' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException] {
    if ($Error[0].Exception.GetType().Name -eq 'DriveNotFoundException') {
        Write-Output "Drive not found."
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Something else went wrong."
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Something else went wrong."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what's happening.  So, given that the original code, as written, works correctly in later version of Powershell, is this something that is specific to v2?  I have little control over what version is on any of the machines the script will be running on, but I know it ranges from 2 to 4.  If the exception is thrown as `DriveNotFoundException` on later versions of PS, I may need to use a bare `catch` and check the error, as much as it pains me to do so.

Comment: Great sleuthing. Given that `$Error[0].Exception` (or `$_.Exception` inside a `catch` handler) contains the _original_ exception even in PS v2-, how did you figure out that `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]` was being matched?

Answer (score 3):

To complement [HAL9256's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612673/45375):

<sup>Note: The following is in part speculative. Do let me know if I'm wrong.</sup>

- The behavior observed is a **presumably a *bug* in PowerShell v1 and v2** , where the ***internal* exception of type `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]` accidentally *masks* the original exception in the matching logic of typed `catch` blocks** in a `try / catch` statement.
- The reason I suspect that `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]` is purely an internal exception that should never have been exposed, is that both `$Error[0].Exception` and its alias inside a `catch` block, `$_.Exception`, reflect the *original* exception, even in PowerShell v1 and v2 - the `$Errors` collection contains no trace of `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]`.
- While the **bug is fixed in v3+**, v3+ *still*, but now *also* matches `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]` in typed `catch` handlers, presumably so as not to break backward compatibility.
- There is **little benefit in catching `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]`**, given its generic nature (it just tells you that *a* cmdlet experienced a non-terminating error).

  - The only conceivable reason for catching it is if you wanted to know whether the exception at hand was *natively* terminating or only treated as terminating due to `-ErrorAction Stop` or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.

Thus, **for code that must also on run v2-, I'd solve the problem as follows**:

```
try {
  # Assumes no Q:\ drive connected.
  $foo = Get-PSDrive -name 'Q' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {  # Use a generic handler to work around the bug in v1 an v2.
  # $_ is the [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] instance representing
  # the PowerShell error at hand (same as $Error[0]).
  # $_.Exception contains the exception that triggered the error,
  # and can be compared to specific exception types with -is.
  if ($_.Exception -is [System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException]) {
    "Drive not found."
  } else {
    "Something else went wrong."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is due to some strange behavior (according to the above comments about later versions of PowerShell), but this does manage to handle the specific error:

```
try {
    $foo = Get-PSDrive -name 'Q' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    if ($Error[0].Exception.GetType().Name -eq 'DriveNotFoundException') {
        Write-Output 'No such drive.'
    }
    else {
        Write-Output 'Something else went wrong.'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a brief post of the final version of the code I used, based on the explanation provided by @HAL9256 in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35612673/1843248):

```
try {
    # Assumes no Q:\ drive connected.
    $foo = Get-PSDrive -name 'Q' -ErrorAction Stop
}
# Catch exceptions thrown by both v2.0 and by later versions.
catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException], `
      [System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException] {
    Write-Output "Drive not found."
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Something else went wrong."
}
```

This has been tested on both PowerShell 2.0 & 4.0 and works on both.  I suppose there's a minor risk that some **other** exception will occur in the `Get-PSDrive` statement in a PowerShell 2.0 environment, triggering the `catch` block, but in my use case, it's an acceptable risk and will trigger a different exception later in the script.